# Adding button bar from navigation to Table View Controller - Obj C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Hey guys I am trying to add a button bar navigation to my `UITableViewController`.  But when I go to add bar button items to the navigation it never shows when I run the app.

[image: results]

[image: bar button]

Not sure why when I start this up the button bar does not show?

Comment: may be you are setting [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
You are setting bar buttons through coding or at interface builder..?

Comment: I am looking at my code for the controller and dont see anything that would hide this.

Comment: check interface builder that you have tick the hidden option for navigation bar.

Comment: @Vidhyanand figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured it out, because of the root class of `table view` it would not show the bottom navigation bar.  So because it was a custom class I simply added the following code:

```
bottomNav = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,  self.view.frame.size.height - 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 44.0)];  
bottomNav.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;  
[self.parentViewController.view addSubview:bottomNav];
```

within a custom method and it worked perfectly!